# Unable to make bootable ubuntu flash drive

Tags: usb, software-installation, mac

I'm trying to dual boot my mac mini with ubuntu 14-1.04.

I don't have a disc drive so i'm using a flash drive to host the info and boot from that but I can't get this to work.

I downloaded the .iso file for ubuntu and go through terminal using the `hdiutil` command to convert it to a .iso file. Once I've done this I have a file which is named ubuntu.iso.dmg.

From there I found out the node of the usb drive which is disk1, I use the `sudo dd` command to write the ubuntu.iso.dmg to the usb drive but it doesnt work, I don't get any errors, it just says invalid argument.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good resources available for making a USB-LiveDisk - [source](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

### How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X

*We would encourage Mac users to download Ubuntu Desktop Edition by burning a CD. But if you prefer to use a USB stick, please follow the instructions below.*

**Note:** this procedure requires that you create an .img file from the .iso file you download. It will also change the filesystem that is on the USB stick to make it bootable, so backup all data before continuing.

**Tip:** Drag and drop a file from Finder to Terminal to 'paste' the full path without risking typing errors.

1) Download Ubuntu Desktop

2) Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).

3) Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil (e.g. `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`)

***Note:*** OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.
4) Run diskutil list to get the current list of devices.

5) Insert your flash media.

6)  Run diskutil list again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).

7) Run diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).

8) Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.img` or `./ubuntu.dmg`).

> **Notes:**
>
> - Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
> - If you see the error `dd: Invalid number '1m'`, you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace `bs=1m` with `bs=1M`
> - If you see the error `dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy`, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive

9)  Run diskutil eject /dev/diskN and remove your flash media when the command completes.

10) Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the .iso is extracted when you put it on the flash drive. By turning it into a .dmg you compressed it more. It needs to be extracted so the 15 or so files and folders are on your flash drive. You also need to make sure that the file system on your flash drive is bootable.